# Invalid date displaying on iPhone

Tags: reactjs, date, momentjs

I noticed my code is displaying invalid date on my iphone, but it is displaying fine on the web side.

```
var dateval = "2012 08 12"
Moment(new Date(dateval)).format("MMM Do YYYY")
```

I tried researching a bit and tried switching the format to "YYYY/MM/DD" but it still doesn't work.

I am using React.js and passing this value down props.

Anyone help would be appreciated

Comment: Try `Moment(new Date(dateval.replace(/\s/g,'/'))).format("MMM Do YYYY")`

Comment: there is a typo `val`, it should be `var` or `const`

Comment: @HaoWu that fixed the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For those who are looking for an answer, I removed the new Date() and it works on iPhone.

```
var dateval = "2012 08 12"
Moment(dateval).format("MMM Do YYYY")
```